# LocalService as HttpResponse listener What does android do when response comes back service not running

Tags: android

I am using LocalService as HttpResponse listener.  It implements the callback listener.  Just wondering what  happens if response comes back when the service is not running.  What will android do? will it restart the service and handle the response? Also not sure how to test this. I am not having a problem with this yet, but just wanted to understand this better.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

If the OS reaped the service, it will attempt to restart it: "Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this happens, the system will later try to restart the service. ..."

From previous experience of binding activities to a background service, once the service dies, and some interaction is attempted on the activity, the entire application crashes (Force Close).

Comment: Ok. So where is the best place to put HttpResponse handlers within the app so that they can receive the response when it comes back? Thanks

Comment: Could you please comment on where to put the Http response handlers if Service is not a good place?  Where else then?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where to put them. Might take some experimentation on your part.